# how to make Google cards always appear?

Tags: google-account, app-widgets, home-screen

I really like the Google card thinghies but I don't like that they disappear.

Is there any way to force them to stay on the home screen as widgets? I want the weather and the currency exchange one to be always there

Comment: Google Now includes a widget. Just add it to your home screen.